# For loop creating histograms with dynamic titles in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dynamic-programming

I am trying to make a series of histograms for each column in my data using a for loop.

Right now I am using this:

```
for (i in dat) {
  p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes({{i}})) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=5, na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggtitle({{i}}) +
    xlab("Rating") +
    ylab("Frequency")
    print(p) 
    ggsave(p, file=paste0({{i}},".jpeg"), width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm", device = "jpeg")
  }
```

This code does create histograms and saves a histogram, but the title of the histogram is 'NA' and the name it is saved under is also 'NA'. Because each one is saved as NA, each one overwrites the last as it saves.

I want the titles and save names to reflect the current column name (ie VariableA, VariableB, VariableC, etc.)

I have tried:

```
ggtitle(i)
```

```
ggtitle([i])
```

```
ggtitle({{i}})
```

```
ggtitle(colnames({{i}}))
```

and the corresponding changes to ggsave, but I cannot get the Title and File name to change to be what the current value of i is.

My data are a data.frame (though I have tried a tibble too).

Comment: Does the histogram that is being saved make any sense? Does your `for` loop create a histogram for each *row* of data in `dat`? Could you try `for (i in names(dat))`?

Comment: Interestingly your code works for me, creating plots named by the first row of data, rather than the `colnames` and saving them as separate files. Perhaps you could share an example of your data.

Comment: Hi Mark, with the data/code the way they are, the histograms produced do make sense. Trying for (i in names(dat)) produced this error: Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?. I did try to create example data, but the example data produced the results you're talking about (three graphs named by the first row of data) while my actual data produce an entirely different results with the same code. I can't figure out why there's that discrepancy-- both are dataframes.